# Add Action Rule Axis Camera

Tags: xml, soap, vapix

I am trying to use the vapix API for Axis cameras to make a new action rule. The responses for this API are hilariously unhelpful. My error is : "The requested SOAP action failed" . I am using SOAPUI 5.2.0. Here is my code which is supposed to make a new action rule:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-encoding" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:c14n="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsa5="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" xmlns:xmime="http://tempuri.org/xmime.xsd" xmlns:xop="http://www.w3.org/2004/08/xop/include" xmlns:wsrfbf="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wsrf/bf-2" xmlns:wstop="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wsn/t-1" xmlns:tt="http://www.onvif.org/ver10/schema" xmlns:acert="http://www.axis.com/vapix/ws/cert" xmlns:wsrfr="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wsrf/r-2" xmlns:aa="http://www.axis.com/vapix/ws/action1" xmlns:acertificates="http://www.axis.com/vapix/ws/certificates" xmlns:aev="http://www.axis.com/vapix/ws/event1" xmlns:ali1="http://www.axis.com/vapix/ws/light/CommonBinding" xmlns:ali2="http://www.axis.com/vapix/ws/light/IntensityBinding" xmlns:ali3="http://www.axis.com/vapix/ws/light/AngleOfIlluminationBinding" xmlns:ali4="http://www.axis.com/vapix/ws/light/DayNightSynchronizeBinding" xmlns:ali="http://www.axis.com/vapix/ws/light" xmlns:apc="http://www.axis.com/vapix/ws/panopsiscalibration1" xmlns:arth="http://www.axis.com/vapix/ws/recordedtour1" xmlns:aweb="http://www.axis.com/vapix/ws/webserver" xmlns:tan1="http://www.onvif.org/ver20/analytics/wsdl/RuleEngineBinding" xmlns:tan2="http://www.onvif.org/ver20/analytics/wsdl/AnalyticsEngineBinding" xmlns:tan="http://www.onvif.org/ver20/analytics/wsdl" xmlns:tds="http://www.onvif.org/ver10/device/wsdl" xmlns:tev1="http://www.onvif.org/ver10/events/wsdl/NotificationProducerBinding" xmlns:tev2="http://www.onvif.org/ver10/events/wsdl/EventBinding" xmlns:tev3="http://www.onvif.org/ver10/events/wsdl/SubscriptionManagerBinding" xmlns:wsnt="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wsn/b-2" xmlns:tev4="http://www.onvif.org/ver10/events/wsdl/PullPointSubscriptionBinding" xmlns:tev="http://www.onvif.org/ver10/events/wsdl" xmlns:timg="http://www.onvif.org/ver20/imaging/wsdl" xmlns:tptz="http://www.onvif.org/ver20/ptz/wsdl" xmlns:trt="http://www.onvif.org/ver10/media/wsdl" xmlns:ter="http://www.onvif.org/ver10/error" xmlns:tns1="http://www.onvif.org/ver10/topics" xmlns:tnsaxis="http://www.axis.com/2009/event/topics">
  <soap:Header/>
  <soap:Body>
    <act:AddActionRule>
    <act:NewActionRule>
      <!--Optional:-->
      <act:Name>AHHHHH</act:Name>
      <act:Enabled>true</act:Enabled>
      <!--Optional:-->
      <!--<act:StartEvent>-->
      <!--You may enter ANY elements at this point-->
      <!--</act:StartEvent>-->
      <!--Optional:-->
      <act:Conditions>
        <!--1 or more repetitions:-->
        <act:Condition>
          <wsnt:TopicExpression Dialect="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wsn/t-1/TopicExpression/Concrete">tns1:Device/ tnsaxis:IO/Port//.</wsnt:TopicExpression>
          <wsnt:MessageContent Dialect="http://www.onvif.org/ver10/tev/messageContentFilter/ItemFilter">boolean(//SimpleItem[@Name="state" and @Value="1"]) and boolean(//SimpleItem[@Name="port" and @Value="0"])</wsnt:MessageContent>
        </act:Condition>
      </act:Conditions>
      <!--Optional:-->
      <!--act:ActivationTimeout>?</act:ActivationTimeout-->
      <act:PrimaryAction>16</act:PrimaryAction>
      <!--Optional:-->
      <!--act:FailoverAction>?</act:FailoverAction-->
    </act:NewActionRule>
  </act:AddActionRule>
</soap:Body>
```

To be honest I am not sure what the things inside the condition are doing. I went into the camera setup and added the action rule through the setup, then used another soap command "GetActionRules" to see how to format it. The GeActionRules command is

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:act="http://www.axis.com/vapix/ws/action1">
   <soap:Header/>
   <soap:Body>
      <act:GetActionRules/>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

And the response is

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-encoding" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:c14n="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsa5="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" xmlns:xmime="http://tempuri.org/xmime.xsd" xmlns:xop="http://www.w3.org/2004/08/xop/include" xmlns:wsrfbf="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wsrf/bf-2" xmlns:wstop="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wsn/t-1" xmlns:tt="http://www.onvif.org/ver10/schema" xmlns:acert="http://www.axis.com/vapix/ws/cert" xmlns:wsrfr="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wsrf/r-2" xmlns:aa="http://www.axis.com/vapix/ws/action1" xmlns:acertificates="http://www.axis.com/vapix/ws/certificates" xmlns:aev="http://www.axis.com/vapix/ws/event1" xmlns:ali1="http://www.axis.com/vapix/ws/light/CommonBinding" xmlns:ali2="http://www.axis.com/vapix/ws/light/IntensityBinding" xmlns:ali3="http://www.axis.com/vapix/ws/light/AngleOfIlluminationBinding" xmlns:ali4="http://www.axis.com/vapix/ws/light/DayNightSynchronizeBinding" xmlns:ali="http://www.axis.com/vapix/ws/light" xmlns:apc="http://www.axis.com/vapix/ws/panopsiscalibration1" xmlns:arth="http://www.axis.com/vapix/ws/recordedtour1" xmlns:aweb="http://www.axis.com/vapix/ws/webserver" xmlns:tan1="http://www.onvif.org/ver20/analytics/wsdl/RuleEngineBinding" xmlns:tan2="http://www.onvif.org/ver20/analytics/wsdl/AnalyticsEngineBinding" xmlns:tan="http://www.onvif.org/ver20/analytics/wsdl" xmlns:tds="http://www.onvif.org/ver10/device/wsdl" xmlns:tev1="http://www.onvif.org/ver10/events/wsdl/NotificationProducerBinding" xmlns:tev2="http://www.onvif.org/ver10/events/wsdl/EventBinding" xmlns:tev3="http://www.onvif.org/ver10/events/wsdl/SubscriptionManagerBinding" xmlns:wsnt="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wsn/b-2" xmlns:tev4="http://www.onvif.org/ver10/events/wsdl/PullPointSubscriptionBinding" xmlns:tev="http://www.onvif.org/ver10/events/wsdl" xmlns:timg="http://www.onvif.org/ver20/imaging/wsdl" xmlns:tptz="http://www.onvif.org/ver20/ptz/wsdl" xmlns:trt="http://www.onvif.org/ver10/media/wsdl" xmlns:ter="http://www.onvif.org/ver10/error" xmlns:tns1="http://www.onvif.org/ver10/topics" xmlns:tnsaxis="http://www.axis.com/2009/event/topics">
   <SOAP-ENV:Header/>
   <SOAP-ENV:Body>
      <aa:GetActionRulesResponse>
         <aa:ActionRules>
            <aa:ActionRule>
               <aa:RuleID>8</aa:RuleID>
               <aa:Name>FTP</aa:Name>
               <aa:Enabled>true</aa:Enabled>
               <aa:Conditions>
                  <aa:Condition>
                     <wsnt:TopicExpression Dialect="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wsn/t-1/TopicExpression/Concrete">tns1:Device/tnsaxis:IO/Port//.</wsnt:TopicExpression>
                     <wsnt:MessageContent Dialect="http://www.onvif.org/ver10/tev/messageContentFilter/ItemFilter">boolean(//SimpleItem[@Name="port" and @Value="0"]) and boolean(//SimpleItem[@Name="state" and @Value="1"])</wsnt:MessageContent>
                  </aa:Condition>
               </aa:Conditions>
               <aa:PrimaryAction>13</aa:PrimaryAction>
           </aa:ActionRule>
            <aa:ActionRule>
               <aa:RuleID>9</aa:RuleID>
               <aa:Name>noobbbb</aa:Name>
               <aa:Enabled>true</aa:Enabled>
               <aa:Conditions>
                  <aa:Condition>
                     <wsnt:TopicExpression Dialect="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wsn/t-1/TopicExpression/Concrete">tns1:Device/tnsaxis:IO/Port//.</wsnt:TopicExpression>
                     <wsnt:MessageContent Dialect="http://www.onvif.org/ver10/tev/messageContentFilter/ItemFilter">boolean(//SimpleItem[@Name="port" and @Value="0"]) and boolean(//SimpleItem[@Name="state" and @Value="1"])</wsnt:MessageContent>
                  </aa:Condition>
               </aa:Conditions>
               <aa:PrimaryAction>14</aa:PrimaryAction>
            </aa:ActionRule>
         </aa:ActionRules>
      </aa:GetActionRulesResponse>
   </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the response, there are added backslashes and periods. I changed

tns1:Device/ tnsaxis:IO/Port//.

to

tns1:Device/tnsaxis:IO/Port

and it worked!